# Fatal error: Class 'Tools' not found in prestashop for method GET

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have included  the tools file path

{include('../../classes/Tools.php');}

Form Method is

```
"method="GET"
<input type="text" id="txtFrom_Date" name="txtFrom_Date" required="" >"
```

and in other php file i have to get the values like below

```
{$from = Tools::getValue('txtFrom_Date', '');}
```

it is throwing the error that

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Tools' not found.

Comment: Why would you do this? Simply pass the value using your controller. Respect MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the `Tools` class in the file that has that form. 
add the line `<?php include("...path_to_file_with_Tools_class.."); ?>`

You should have displayed the file with the `Tools` class.

Comment: I have added the path to the file also which is in the classes and tools.php, then also it is throwing the same error.

Comment: you path is incorrect: use `{include('../../classes/Tools.php');}` instead of  `{ include('/../../classes/Tools.php'); }` And please wrap code in `` or click on the {} icon before posting code to make it more visible

Comment: Thank you. But after changing that also it didn't worked.I have downloaded the latest tools.php file also. still it is not working.

Comment: Respect the PrestaShop MVC